# How to determine if a number is negative, including -0

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, zero

I need to define a `sign` function which returns either `-1` or `1`. The `Math.sign` function does not suffices since it returns `-0` and`0` respectively for the inputs `-0` and `0`.

My first attempt at solving this was...

```
function my_sign(a) {
    let sign = Math.sign(a);
    if (sign === 0 || sign === 1){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Although, since `0 === -0` is `true`, this does not work. How to proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure how JS stores `-0` but `console.log(-0);`is `0`.

Comment: The idea in the dulicate works... but it's in Java. Isn't there a better approach in JS?

Comment: It works in JS too https://jsfiddle.net/7p8wt4km/5/ For more background-information look https://medium.com/coding-at-dawn/is-negative-zero-0-a-number-in-javascript-c62739f80114

Comment: @Sascha By the way, I believe not all machines permit a -0. Might be why you don't have one. The duplicate does work, so I will proceed with that. But it feels weird there isn't a copySign function or something similar.